# Debug in different flash projects in one workspace

Tags: flash, air, adobe

I'm writing application in Adobe Flash Builder 4.5 using AIR 3 SDK. I want to debug throw swf files which downloaded from the internet.

```
My project consist of:
1. MainProject (Android Mobile app proj)
2. LibFile (flex project)
3. ExtraGame (web app using LibFile).
```

So, when I build .swf file from LibFile+ExtraGAme, load it from internet and run it from MainProject in different Application domains - I can't debug in ExtraGAme project.

**So how can I debug such projects?? Thanks a lot.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about Your technical setup. However I often have to deal with debugging .swf's loaded from within other .swf's.

Thus I resort to remote debuggers that use localconnection to provide a trace log at runtime regardless of Your .swf is embedded in another .swf.

I've found that both [HexagonStar's Alcon debugger](http://www.hexagonstar.com/project/alcon/) and [De MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/) to be excellent tools.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: It is useful answer, thanks, but now I'm using such way: I compile project in debug mode, and then load .swf file to server. After that I'm loading that application to my main application, and I have a possibility to debug throw that version.